# How to make a domain model for this endpoint result?

Tags: angular

I want to create a domain model for this api endpoint result.

**Endpoint result**

```
{
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2018-04-08",
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 1.565,
    "CHF": 1.1798,
    "GBP": 0.87295,
    "SEK": 10.2983,
    "EUR": 1.092,
    "USD": 1.2234,
    .........
  }
}
```

And how to store the returned value in caller component.

Comment: OK. what's stopping you ?

Comment: Be like Nike. Just do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a class with the given attributes as follows.

```
export class YourClass{
    base: string;
    date: date;
    rates: Array<{currency: string, rate: number}>;
}
```

Then you could use this class as your model when subscribing to a service.

```
yourService.subscribe(
    data:YourClass => { // do something with it},
    error => { // handle error})
```

Comment: But when I subscribed the returned result to a variable in component and want to access, its throwing an error, like "base" can not be a property of none type